# Are there any security related rules in PCI-DSS that govern when I can capture a payment?

Tags: pci-dss, compliance

Is there a PCI-DSS rule that a merchant cannot capture the funds for an order until we have actually shipped it?

I can't seem to find an official reference that describes this as a PCI DSS requirement.  Is it one?  If so, where can I find it?

Comment: Where have you heard this? As far as I know, PCI DSS doesn't really care about payment processing at this level. To be honest, this is the first time I hear of such thing.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has nothing to do with information security.

Comment: You won't find one because it isn't a requirement, just an option, albeit probably the most common option, which may be why you were under the impression it was required.

Comment: @Xander, does an "option" have some specific meaning in the context of PCI DSS?  You mentioned it's "probably the most common option."  What are the other options which are "less" common?

Comment: @Adrian, regarding this being off-topic: what would be a more appropriate stack exchange site to post this on?  I searched for PCI DSS questions, and this site seemed to be where most of them were located, so I thought this would be the most appropriate site for a PCI DSS question.

Comment: @Adnan I think PCI DSS is in scope of security.se. Primarly because it stands for Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard and Data Security is in scope of our website.

Comment: No, no special meaning that I'm aware of in the context of PCI.  They're more accounting driven than anything, and the options could potentially be any scheme you could think up.  I'm not aware of any restrictions specific to PCI.  Perhaps the next most common option, however, would be capture at sale.

Comment: @LucasKauffman I'm not sure why would anyone infer that I meant that PCI DSS is outside our scope. I explicitly mentioned that AT THIS LEVEL this has nothing to do with PCI DSS, this THE QUESTION is outside our scope because it's about things unrelated to PCI DSS (sending money and shipping).

Comment: In fact, most businesses have the opposite policy of requiring cleared payment before shipping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PCI DSS doesn't cover such topics as these.  What you're looking for are the various card brand operating regulations.  From a security/risk management perspective for ecommerce, Visa also has this guide:  http://usa.visa.com/download/merchants/e-comm-merch-guide-to-risk-and-security-vol032413.pdf

Answer (score 3):

The matters of payment capture and shipping aren't covered or related to PCI DSS.

Answer (score 3):

PCI-DSS is a security document concerned with how to properly secure Personal Credit Information.  Regulations about capture of payments are unrelated to data security and thus are not covered by PCI-DSS.

You may be thinking of merchant service requirements which are contractual obligations with either your payment processor or your merchant bank, but they are not security related.